# ttl of list is disappear when the list become empty in redis

Tags: redis

In Redis I inserted an element into a list by using Lpush and set an expiry. During the program execution, more elements will push-in and pop-out to and from the list. But when the list become empty the settled  expiry of the list will loss. 
Is there any way to retain the old list even if it is empty??

As a hack I put a dummy object in Redis for persist it's ttl but that is a bad solution.

please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, empty lists are being removed. See the docs where it says: [the result will be an empty list (which causes key to be removed)](http://redis.io/commands/LTRIM)

As an alternative you can use a separate simple key for keeping the expiration. You will have to check on every push and pop if the key has expired or not and to do this in an atomic way you can use a Lua script. I think this separation is better than a dummy object which can be confused with a real value. And your whole logic would be in the Lua script and not in your application.

Comment: Using another key for expiration is a nice solution, but still i have an over head of checking expiry on each push and pop (redis call is a little bit costly)

Comment: Setting a key to expire is O(1), checking the TTL on a key is O(1). Stop worrying and start measuring, there are ways to monitor the redis performance and latency: http://redis.io/topics/latency-monitor

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution is the most feasible option now.
<br>
I thought there will be some way to retain the key of the original list.

Comment: you're welcome, if it helps you you can always up and approve :)